# Does anyone have experience simultaneously running a Drupal and Wordpress site and redirecting some links from Drupal to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drupal, proxy, blogs

**This is a really weird question and I apologize:**

I've been asked if it's possible not to import our blog from Wordpress to Drupal but just keep it in Wordpress as an archive and re-direct our users say from *hostname/blog/...* to *hostname/wordpress/*... when a URL matches the Wordpress URL pattern.

I've never heard of anyone trying this and I'm wondering about pitfalls and whether or not it's even possible.

Thanks!

D

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe this will be possible by configure how mod_rewrite handles calls to *hostname/blog/* , and *hostname/wordpress/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it should be pretty simple to do.  I plan to take advantage of the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module for apache:

We will just need to configure a **.htaccess**  file to **redirect** URLs matching *hostname/blog/pattern/* - where *pattern* fits a Wordpress URL blog pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I use mod_rewrite on my Drupal site.  Here's an example I use to redirect users to `www.earldouglas.com` when they access `earldouglas.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^earldouglas.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.earldouglas.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You could try something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yeah, we did end up doing something very similar to this.